# Cross site collection gobal nav in sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, global-navigation

On sp 2019, i am planning to use modern team sites and comm sites as separate site collections. Is there a way to have global nav as hubsites are not available for 2019, perhaps via managed metadata or something? Please share thoughts if someone implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You could use manage metadata to share global navigation between site collections.

Reference:

[Manage metadata to share global navigation between site collections](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/04/19/share-global-navigation-between-site-collections/)

2.You could use code to share global navigation between site collections.

Reference:

[Cross Site Collection Navigation for Modern & Classic SharePoint Sites](http://thomasdaly.net/2019/08/28/cross-site-collection-navigation-for-modern-classic-sharepoint-sites/)